# SQL Server : get top 5 and count over 2 columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am currently creating a top 5 predictions overview for a soccer prediction program using a SQL  Server 2012 SE database.

I have a table named `Userpredictions` with 2 columns: `team1score`, `team2score`.

These columns contain the predictions the user gives a certain match.

I need to get a top 5 selection of how many times the combinations of these columns are given. So not a top 5 of how many times team1score was 0,1,2,etc... but a top 5 occurring of the combination  team1score and team2score

And if possible, the count of occurring times these predictions were made as well

I was thinking of first selecting a distinct of all the team1score and team2score combinations, and then adding the count to them and sort them by that count and cut till i have only the top 5 but i don't know how to form the query in SQL Server

Comment: Can you share some sample data and output you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT TOP (5)
    TeamScore1, 
    TeamScore2,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    dbo.UserPredictions
GROUP BY
    TeamScore1, 
    TeamScore2
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

You basically just count how many times each pair of (`TeamScore1`, `TeamScore2`) exists, and you order that list of values by the count descending, and pick the top 5 of those.